# Parallel version of the `std::generate` performs worse than the sequential one

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, c++17, tbb

I'm trying to parallelize some old code using the [Execution Policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution) from the C++ 17. My sample code is below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;

constexpr auto NUM = 100'000'000U;

double func()
{
  return rand();
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> v(NUM);
  // ------ feature testing
  std::cout << "__cpp_lib_execution         : " << __cpp_lib_execution << std::endl;
  std::cout << "__cpp_lib_parallel_algorithm: " << __cpp_lib_parallel_algorithm << std::endl;
  // ------ fill the vector with random numbers sequentially
  auto const startTime1 = Clock::now();
  std::generate(std::execution::seq, v.begin(), v.end(), func);
  Duration const elapsed1 = Clock::now() - startTime1;
  std::cout << "std::execution::seq: " << elapsed1.count() << " sec." << std::endl;
  // ------ fill the vector with random numbers in parallel
  auto const startTime2 = Clock::now();
  std::generate(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), func);
  Duration const elapsed2 = Clock::now() - startTime2;
  std::cout << "std::execution::par: " << elapsed2.count() << " sec." << std::endl;
}
```

The program output on my Linux desktop:

```
__cpp_lib_execution         : 201902
__cpp_lib_parallel_algorithm: 201603
std::execution::seq: 0.971162 sec.
std::execution::par: 25.0349 sec.
```

Why does the parallel version performs 25 times worse than the sequential one?

Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0

Comment: Are actually interested in parallel random number generation, or did you just use it as a stand-in?

Comment: @paleonix - this is just a test, in my real project there are no any random numbers. I just want to better understand the STL behavior.

Comment: Good, parallel random number generation is a whole can of worms one should only get into when really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The thread-safety of `rand` is implementation-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand). Which means either:

1. Your code is *wrong* in the parallel case, or
2. It's effectively serial, with a highly contended lock, which would dramatically increase the overhead in the parallel case and get incredibly poor performance.

Based on your results, I'm guessing #2 applies, but it could be *both*.

Either way, the answer is: **`rand` is a terrible test case for parallelism.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll get rid of the `rand`

Comment: @HEKTO: In response to your later question edit: You realize factoring the `rand` call out to a different function doesn't change anything, right? It's *possible* using a lambda or functor (not just a plain function) might make some difference (by allowing the compiler to specialize the template for `std::generate` such that it can directly, statically, call `rand`, where it might otherwise have to call `rand` through a function pointer), but it won't fix the fundamental issue with `rand` being a bad test case for parallelism (being wrong, slow, or both).

Comment: Yes, sure, I understand that. I've just moved the `rand` function to another function to experiment with various ways to initialize the vector. It looks clearer to call a single function with all four execution policies.